# Error in View in R : unused argument

Tags: r, view, environment

I was working on some functions in R when the session crashed and I had to terminate the session and restart. Upon restart I could no longer view any objects in my project, when i try View(x) I get the following message:

```
Error in View : unused argument  (envir = globalenv())
```

I cant figure out what has happened and how I reset it, I have not been working on any global settings or environment settings so I don't really get it.

All solutions are appreciated

Best,
David

Comment: Was the environment saved to an image before it crashed? What was the working directory...etc...need more info

Comment: Also..check your history for prior work